# ASP.NET ReportViewer Server Report Render Stream results in exception

Tags: asp.net, reportviewer2008

I'm trying to use the `ServerReport.RenderStream` method from the ASP.NET ReportViewer (2008 SP1), but I'm getting a `rsStreamNotFound` exception from the method. I've tried the two different lines of code below after setting the parameters. I'm interfacing with SQL Server 2005 and SSRS 2005. I've seen articles about a hotfix for this issue, but I'd really rather not resort to a hotfix, as I'm not sure that IT will be OK with it going in. There isn't too much documentation that I've found on the error which is

> The stream cannot be found. The stream
>   identifier that is provided to an
>   operation cannot be located in the
>   report server database.report server database.

Prep Code:

```
string mimeType;
string encoding;
List<ReportParameter> parameters = new List<ReportParameter>();
string startDateValue = Request.Form[startDate.UniqueID];

string endDateValue = Request.Form[endDate.UniqueID];
parameters.Add(new ReportParameter("Owner", "5", false));
parameters.Add(new ReportParameter("StartDate", startDateValue, false));
parameters.Add(new ReportParameter("EndDate", endDateValue, false));
ReportViewer1.ServerReport.SetParameters(parameters);
```

Call 1:

```
byte[] result = ReportViewer1.ServerReport.RenderStream("PDF", string.Empty, string.Empty, out mimeType, out encoding);
```

Call 2:

```
byte[] result = ReportViewer1.ServerReport.RenderStream("CSV", string.Empty, string.Empty, out mimeType, out encoding);
```

Clean up:

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = mimeType;
Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(encoding);
Response.OutputStream.Write(result, 0, result.Length);
```

Any thoughts on a solution? The end goal is to write this out to CSV for a download. In reality I'd be happy with XML that I'd translate to CSV.report server database.

Comment: I was able to get around this issue by using ServerReport.Render instead of RenderStream. I don't know what or why the issue presented itself, but Render achieved my goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, the Render method does exactly what I want it to do. I'd love to hear from someone that has experience on RenderStream though.

Answer (score 2):

[RenderStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.webforms.serverreport.renderstream%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) is used to take an existing Stream and process it in a different manner or render external resources, so `Render` was what you needed all along. The C# signature of `RenderStream` is

```
public byte[] RenderStream (
    string format,
    string streamId, //cannot be String.Empty!
    string deviceInfo,
    out string mimeType,
    out string encoding
)
```

The second parameter, `streamId`, is the ID of an existing Stream; you were passing `String.Empty`, hence the error message of not finding the identifier. You can get the StreamID(s) with `out string[] streams` from one of the [Render() methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252214%28v=vs.90%29.aspx):

```
public override byte[] Render (
    string format,
    string deviceInfo,
    out string mimeType,
    out string encoding,
    out string fileNameExtension,
    out string[] streams, //"The stream identifiers. You can use them to render external resources (images, for example) that are associated with the report."
    out Warning[] warnings
)
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/682188/printing-serverreport-without-preview) deals more with using Render and RenderStream.

(I realize the question is a year old, but I thought I'd post what I found for anyone else who stumbles upon it.)