# Send a report directly to printer with Reporting Services

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, .net-4.0

I want to print a report from a button click. I just don't need (in fact, I don't want) to view the report before printing. Just pass some parameters and send it to printer (doesn't matter if it's with or without a print dialog).

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/682188/printing-serverreport-without-preview

Answer (score 1):

Here is a guide from MSDN for doing it with client-side reports:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252091%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

and server reports:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlreportingservices/thread/25973909-592e-42fc-a454-dadda2604882

Comment: Both apply to winforms, not to asp.net.