# SSRS print multiple reports from one parameter

Tags: reporting-services

I have three reports that all use the same parameter. I want to print two reports to a single printer and one of the reports (labels) to a different printer. All in one click.

Comment: You won't be able to do this with what SSRS gives you out of the box. Here is a very similar question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116303/send-a-report-directly-to-printer-with-reporting-services

Comment: If you are using a web page the following modified could be what you are looking for. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252091.aspx

Comment: You can print all reports with one click but only to the same printer. To do this you can create a main report which will call all the other reports with the same parameters.