# Render SSRS .RDL-File to PDF and print it straightly without overviewing it

Tags: pdf, reporting-services, printing

as it has turned out from the title im looking for a solution to print a rendered .rdl Report (rdl to pdf) straightly to a printer/default printer without overviewing it.
Is there a way to do this via Report-Server URL or any other solution?

Something like:

```
http://myrshost/ReportServer?/myreport&rs:Format=PDF |(+print)
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Did you search anywhere before posting this question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Printing ServerReport without Preview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/682188/printing-serverreport-without-preview)

Comment: Add existing files report.rdlc and data.xml

    From the Project menu, select Add Existing Item. The Add Existing Item dialog box will appear.

    Navigate to the folder where you saved report.rdlc and data.xml. Select both files.

    Click Add. The two files appear in Solution Explorer as part of the project. *EDIT* at this point i dont now where to find this two items. I've got only my .rdl File, is there a way to convert or seperate it into rdlc&xml? I'm really new at reporting services, sorry for that.